# DBContext.ChangeTracker not detecting changes to an Array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, entity-framework, data-binding

My EF6 project in VB.NET maps to a MySQL database using the following mapping:

```
Partial Public Class WorkRule 
    Public Property WorkRuleID As Integer 'Maps to int
    Public Property Description As String 'Maps to tinytext
    Public Property RegularTime As Byte() 'Maps to tinyblob
End Class
```

If I edit the Description textbox, changes are detected and saved as expected upon calling .SaveChanges. However, if I edit the content of one of the textboxes bound to an array element, the bound element is changed but the change is not detected by the DBContext.ChangeTracker and the changes are not saved to the database upon calling .SaveChanges.

I can force a save by manually setting the DBContext.Entry().State=EntityState.Modified but is there a better way to do this so changes to the array elements are automatically detected? Should I be using something other than an array perhaps?

Code follows:

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox x:Name="lstWorkRules"/>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=lstWorkRules, Path=SelectedItem}">
            <Label>Description:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
            <Label>Day 1:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RegularTime[0]}"/>
            <Label>Day 2:</Label>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=RegularTime[1]}"/>
            <Label>Etc.</Label>
            <Button Click="Button_Click">Save</Button>
        </StackPanel>

    </Grid>
```

VB:

```
Imports System.Data.Entity

Class MainWindow
    Dim wrContext As WorkRuleEntities

    Private Sub Window_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        wrContext = New WorkRuleEntities
        wrContext.WorkRules.Load

        lstWorkRules.ItemsSource = wrContext.WorkRules.Local
        lstWorkRules.DisplayMemberPath = "Description"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)
        wrContext.SaveChanges()
    End Sub
End Class
```